# Typeorm with nestjs getting error: syntax error at or near "NOT" when i run migration

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs, typeorm

Hi there i am using typeorm with nest js. everything is working fine.Migrations are created as i want but there is a problem when i try to make a column primary having a primary key of uuid
Here is the code

```
import {MigrationInterface, QueryRunner, Table} from "typeorm";

export class StudentsResponseTable1616216067510 implements MigrationInterface {

    public async up(queryRunner: QueryRunner): Promise<void> {
        await queryRunner.createTable(new Table({
            name: 'students',
            columns: [
                {
                    name: 'id',
                    type: 'varchar',
                    isGenerated: true,
                    generationStrategy: 'uuid',
                    isPrimary: true
                },
                {
                    name: 'feedback',
                    type: 'jsonb',
                }
            ]
        }))
    }

    public async down(queryRunner: QueryRunner): Promise<void> {
    }

}
```

and i receive this error

```
  length: 92,
  severity: 'ERROR',
  code: '42601',
  detail: undefined,
  hint: undefined,
  position: '31',
  internalPosition: undefined,
  internalQuery: undefined,
  where: undefined,
  schema: undefined,
  table: undefined,
  column: undefined,
  dataType: undefined,
  constraint: undefined,
  file: 'scan.l',
  line: '1180',
  routine: 'scanner_yyerror',
  query: 'CREATE TABLE "students" ("id" NOT NULL DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4(), "feedback" jsonb NOT NULL, CONSTRAINT "PK_7d7f07271ad4ce999880713f05e" PRIMARY KEY ("id"))',
  parameters: []
```

Thank you for taking time and providing solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use `generationStrategy: 'uuid'` the column type must be `'uuid'`. Unfortunately there is some obsolete information on the web that states you should use `'varchar'`. This is wrong: you need `'uuid'`.

Also, if you haven't done so already, you must run the following command on your database to use uuid generationStrategy:

```
CREATE EXTENSION "uuid-ossp";
```

Comment: i am using typeorm and when i change from `varchar` to `uuid` then the user table migrates successfully. But, when i apply foreign key to another table that references this then i receive **error**. so i switched back from `columnType uuid` to `varchar`